# Gridview is not being updated with my sql

Tags: mysql, gridview

I am trying to update the mysql db through griview but when i click update button no change made here is my sql datasource code but this not working

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GisConnectionString %>"
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GisConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT vehicleno, cnic, isaccepted, gname, fname, haulagecode FROM gis.registration WHERE (regno = ?)&#13;&#10;and vehicleno=?"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE gis.registration SET vehicleno =?, cnic =?, isaccepted =?, gname =?, fname = ?, haulagecode = ?&#13;&#10;where regno=?&#13;&#10;and vehicleno=?">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="?" PropertyName="Text" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" Name="?" PropertyName="Text" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="vehicleno" DbType="string" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="cnic" DbType="string"/>
                <asp:Parameter Name="isaccepted" DbType="string" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="gname" DbType="string"/>
                <asp:Parameter Name="fname" DbType="string"/>
                <asp:Parameter Name="haulagecode" DbType="string"/>
                <asp:Parameter Name="regno" DbType="string"/>
                <asp:Parameter Name="vehicleno" DbType="string"/>
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Any Help Will be appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks a Lot I got My answer my self

Comment: anyway consider what I told. if no answer for your question yet and you found answer yourself either delete question or post your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the Solution

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GisConnectionString %>"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GisConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT vehicleno, cnic, isaccepted, gname, fname, haulagecode FROM gis.registration WHERE (regno = IFNULL(?, regno)) AND (companycode = ?)"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE gis.registration SET vehicleno =?, cnic =?, isaccepted =?, gname =?, fname = ?, haulagecode = ? where regno=?">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="?" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Label1" Name="?" PropertyName="Text" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="vehicleno" DbType="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="cnic" DbType="String"/>
        <asp:Parameter Name="isaccepted" DbType="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="gname" DbType="String"/>
        <asp:Parameter Name="fname" DbType="String"/>
        <asp:Parameter Name="haulagecode" DbType="String"/>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" DbType="String" Name="regno" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="vehicleno" DbType="String"/>
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```